# Bind Dynamic Dropdowns with ng-Options with pre-loaded data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Please while helping, don't use 'angular-directive'.
You can help me through jquery, pure javascript or angular

```
 <html ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>
       <select ng-model="m.roleId" ng-change="loadPersons(m.roleId)" ng-options="w.roleId as w.roleName for w in roles">
                    <option value=""></option>
       </select>

       <select ng-model="m.contactId" ng-options="w.contactId as w.personName for w in personList">
                    <option value=""></option>
        </select>

        <button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
        <button ng-click="click(m)">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Please refere to    http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/ZwwH7/3/   fiddle, automatically you will come to know what i want as i've put appropriate msgs.

Fiddle will tell you everything please open up that fiddle right now to help me.

Now My .js file

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    alert('as page loads, I want these two Dropdows as they come (no change)')
    $scope.roles=[{ roleId:1, roleName:"Admin"},{roleId:2,roleName:"guest"}];
    $scope.persons = [{contactId: 1,roleId:1,personName: "Joy"},
                      {contactId: 2,roleId:1,personName: "Jack"},
                      {contactId: 3,roleId:1,personName: "Jonh"},
                      {contactId: 4,roleId:2,personName: "Gereth"}];

     $scope.loadPersons=function(id)
     {
          $scope.personList=[];
           angular.forEach($scope.persons,function(person)
                {
                    if(person.roleId==id)
                    {
                        $scope.personList.push(person);
                    }
                })
       };
     $scope.addRow=function()
     {
        alert('as I click this button, I want same dropdowns with pre-loaded data dynamically in next line and so on');
     }

     $scope.click=function(data)
     {   console.log(data.roleId);
         console.log(data.contactId);
     }
```

}

Comment: I understand what you want. I do not understand why you insist on not using a directive to do it. It is the correct way, that is what they are there for, and it is incredibly easy. All you need is a scope wrapper around each row of your model, and that is the directive's job. I am writing this in a comment rather than an answer so you can choose. If you want to know the right way (with directives) reply back and I'll provide an answer that uses them with a working jsFiddle or Plunkr. Otherwise just ignore this comment.

Comment: is there any else way you can help with? its really needed. please help without using directive first.but if u r also stuck like me n dont know any other way, at last show me with directive way. thanks.

Comment: I provided an answer using a Directive. I want to clarify something: the use of a Directive here is not because either of us is "stuck". It is the *right* way to do this in the first place. Doing it another way would only be desirable if you were having trouble getting the Directive working, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you are trying to do - I am still guessing a little from your description. But it seems as though you are trying to manage a list of people, and each person can also be the contact for another person. And you wish this list to have the option of adding new people.

To illustrate the use of a directive I created this Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hz5oGFXcd55AsFLpO5GJ?p=preview

It is not so much that a Directive is **necessary** for this... but it makes for a very good code structure. All of the work involved in managing an individual person is in one code block and template (person) and all of the work involved in managing the LIST is in another. This makes for easy maintenance and readability.

A directive here is very simple. It is not much more than a controller with a few extra flags:

```
myApp.directive('person', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      person: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'person.html',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.click = function() {
        alert('You clicked person ID ' + $scope.person.contactId);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

You don't really need to do much with these extra parameters because you're almost always going to use the same flags when using this pattern. But basically they tell Angular to make a new HTML element that you can use in things like your list of persons, to take a parameter called "person" (which you use in the ng-repeat), and what template to use. And you put your per-entry code and callbacks (like the per-row click handler) into the link function here. This directive has a controller underneath it automatically.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help Robinson. But I've done it with JQuery and Angular (without directive).One more thing, there is no right and wrong way as programming depends upon your current scenario and you have to think accordingly. I'm not against of directives. In fact, I like to use directive but situation forced me to do something else. nevertheless, i did it. Again thanks for showing your interest.